# service = build("fusiontables", "v1", http=http) cannot get to work

Tags: python, google-fusion-tables, google-api-python-client

I'm using common [google-api-python-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client) to access to Fusion Tables API and cannot do anything useful with it.

Well, I've read help for functions:

```
service = build("fusiontables", "v1")
help(service)
```

and got this:

```
class Resource(__builtin__.object)
 |  A class for interacting with a resource.
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self)
 |  
 |  column = methodResource(self)
 |      A collection resource.
 |  
 |  query = methodResource(self)
 |      A collection resource.
 |  
 |  style = methodResource(self)
 |      A collection resource.
 |  
 |  table = methodResource(self)
 |      A collection resource.
 |  
 |  template = methodResource(self)
 |      A collection resource.
```

and still it didn't give me anything.

I've tried the code from [sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/source/browse/samples/service_account/tasks.py)

```
f = file('key.p12', 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
    '...',
    key,
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables')
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build("fusiontables", "v1", http=http)
print(service.table().list().execute())
```

It gave me "{u'kind': u'fusiontables#tableList'}".

But still I didn't get it how to run SQL queries, how to insert rows to table?
Could you please explain that moment?

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler specifically Fusion Table Client python code at: http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables-client-python/  I've used this successfully.

Comment: Thank you. I've found out this library later then google-api-python-client so I've decided to make google-api work.) But seems like I will use fusion-tables-client after all.

Comment: I've tried that library. It is not very good because it lacks support of service account.(